# How to verify if a folder exists in google shared drives

Tags: php, google-drive-api, php-curl

I wrote the following function to check if a folder exists in Google Drive. It works normally but if the folder is in shared drives it doesn't work. How can I do?

```
    public function ExistsFolderOnDrive($access_token, $folder_name, $parent_folder_id) {

        $query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false and name='$folder_name' and '$parent_folder_id' in parents";

        $apiURL = self::DRIVE_FILES_URI . "?q=" . urlencode($query);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token));

        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($http_code != 200) {
            $error_msg = 'Failed to retrieve folder from Google Drive';
            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
            }
            throw new Exception('Error ' . $http_code . ': ' . $error_msg);
        }

        if (empty($data['files'])) {
            // The folder doesn't exist 
            return false;
        } else {
            // Folder exists, return folder information
            return $data['files'][0]['id'];
        }
    }
```

I tried adding

```
'sharedWithMe' in parents
```

or even

```
and ('$parent_folder_id' in parents or 'sharedWithMe' in parents)
```

to the query but it doesn't work. I'm looking for some suggestions on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your following question,

> It works normally but if the folder is in shared drives it doesn't work. How can I do?

In the case of your showing script, in order to search the shared drive, how about modifying it as follows?

#### From:

```
$apiURL = self::DRIVE_FILES_URI . "?q=" . urlencode($query);
```

#### To:

```
$apiURL = self::DRIVE_FILES_URI . "?q=" . urlencode($query) . "&corpora=allDrives&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true";
```

#### References:

- [Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)

Comment: Perfect, I also applied your suggestions to my other functions to check if a file exists, to create a folder, to upload a file and to delete it. All is well, except in the latter case where, even though I am an administrator with all privileges, he replies: 
"“code”: 403, “message”: “The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.”. 
Do you know something about it?

Comment: @Ampopo Thank you for replying. About `in the latter case where, even though I am an administrator with all privileges, he replies: "“code”: 403, “message”: “The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.”. Do you know something about it?`, although I'm not sure about your actual situation, how about confirming the file about `The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file`? If you have no permission, when you access the file, an error might occur. I apologize that I cannot answer clearly.